# SQL date variable hardcoded

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an SQL query that is hard coded to look at the results prior to today's date. For example

```
select * 
from test
where date between (sysdate-1) and (sysdate)
```

I would like to replace the 1 in (sysdate-1) with a variable like ONE_DAY and to establish that variable as equal to 1.

```
ONE_DAY = 1

select * 
from test
where date between (sysdate-ONE_DAY) and (sysdate)
```

I am using Oracle SQL developer and this is just to prevent hardcoded values in my where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a Bind variable

```
VARIABLE  one_day NUMBER
EXEC :one_day := 1
select * from test where some_date 
between SYSDATE - :one_day and sysdate
```

or a Substitution variable

```
DEFINE one_day = 1
select * from test where some_date 
between SYSDATE - &one_day and sysdate
```

In SQL developer, use run as Script (F5) option

Read more at:

[**Literals, Substitution Variables and Bind Variables**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables)